# SQL management studio actions through GUI usually giving errors when SQL commands aren't

Tags: ms-sql

This is a bit of a noob question: while using SQL server management studio many times when I'm performing actions such as, for example, changing data type (a non primary/foreign key text field from nvarchar(255) to varchar(50)) in an imported table where I'm already sure there won't be any truncation), the application returns an error claiming that the table must be dropped and recreated. This doesn't happen when I perform the same action through SQL. Is there an explanation for this behaviour? I was thinking that "under the hood" SQLSMS would interpret requests from the GUI by translating them in SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly.

I think you must go on **Managament studio -> Tools-> Options -> Designers** and remove tick from **Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation**.